# File Array of Strings

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

i want to ask if there is a way to store or write multiple lines of String array in a file from console. For example:

```
John 19 California
Justin 20 LA
Helena 10 NY
```

I just want to get some idea on how to do it using FileWriter or PrintWriter or anything related t this problem.

Comment: you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13707602/2180785)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Java 7, you could use the [`Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) method.

Here's an example:

```
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] arr = {"John 19 California", 
                        "Justin 20 LA", 
                        "Helena 10 NY"};
        Path p = Files.write(new File("content.txt").toPath(), 
                             Arrays.asList(arr),
                             StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Wrote content to "+p);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, go through all the `String`s in your array and write them to the desired file using `FileWriter`.

```
String[] strings = { "John 19 California",
    "Justin 20 LA",
    "Helena 10 NY" };
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/your/file/path/foo.txt"));
for (String string : strings) {
    bw.write(string);
    bw.newLine();
}
bw.close();
```

Comment: this is good. how if user have to key in the details from the console and the save it in the file? is it possible to do so?

Comment: @rilakkuma read the user input first, store the data in an array or in a `List<String>`, then dump the content into a file. To resolve a problem, split it into smaller problems and solve each problem at a time.

Comment: if i want to split it then i have to create another file to store the split details?