# Can someone explain me why this code doesnt put numbers in my txt file

Tags: java

I want  this programme to write numbers in my txt file but instead of that it writes some strange signs.Does anyone can fix it and make it write numbers from the array

```
package int1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class broj_u_skl {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File a = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop");
    File b = new File(a,"Pisem.txt");
    try {
    b.createNewFile();
}catch(Exception e) {

}
    FileOutputStream st = null;
    try {
        st = new FileOutputStream(b);
    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
```

this is that array:

```
    int[] c = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

but it doesnt write this numbers above.

```
    ByteBuffer bff = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
    FileChannel ch = st.getChannel();
    IntBuffer ib = bff.asIntBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        ib.put(c[i]);

    }
    bff.position(4*ib.position());
    bff.flip();
    try {
        ch.write(bff);
    }catch(IOException e) {

    }






   }
   }
```

Comment: Close the `st` when you're done writing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either close st in finally clause

```
FileOutputStream st = null;
try {
    st = new FileOutputStream(b);
    ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    ...
} finally {
    st.close();
}
```

or a better solution is to use a try-with-resources clause which will close st for you.

```
try (FileOutputStream st = new FileOutputStream(b)) {
   ...
} catch(Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: try-with-resources should really be the first thing to recommend

Answer (score 0):

Add following code

```
finally{
 st.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What this is doing is writing the integers as bytes to the file, not as ascii strings.

Have a look at the example at [how to write an array to a file Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707223/how-to-write-an-array-to-a-file-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your writing integers as bytes, but to have them correctly shown as ascii strings change your `IntBuffer` to an `CharBuffer` :

```
    CharBuffer charBuffer = byteBuffer.asCharBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            charBuffer.put("" + c[i]);
        }
```

and don't forget to flush and close your FileOutputStream:

```
    finally {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

Comment: But than why would i use IntBuffer when i can anytime convert number to string and put it in CharBuffer?