# How can you read boolean array from OutputStreamWriter?

Tags: android, save, local-storage, storage, saving-data

```
public void writeArraytofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("array.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(Arrays.toString(array));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}
```

I think I've found how to write an array to a file, but I still do not know how to read one. Can someone show me how it works?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read a file into an array? Clarify in the body of the question.

Comment: I am trying to read the array that I have saved @jdv

Comment: You can use a Reader to fetch the data from the file, but I think you might be going at this the wrong way. I'm not even sure you really want to write out the contents this way (read up on what Arrays.toString() really does.) However, what you are doing is sort of writing your own serialization/deserialization routines.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343689/1531971 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13707223/1531971